# How to Map Nullable Guid Field with Sqlprovider in F#

Tags: f#

I am getting the error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid'
to type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1
```

with this code:

```
let products = 
    query {
        for product in ctx.Dbo.Products do
            select product
    } 
    |> Seq.map(fun p -> p.MapTo<Product>())
    |> Seq.toList
```

I have narrowed my Type down to just a few fields to see what is going on

```
type Product = {
    Id: Guid
    SellDiscountCalcTypeId: Option<Guid>
    Code: string
}
```

And my data provider is set up  correctly ( useOptionTypes = true )

```
type smBoomProvider =
    SqlDataProvider<
        DatabaseVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER,
        ConnectionString = smBoomConn,
        IndividualsAmount = 1000,
        UseOptionTypes = true
    >
```

For a field with all nulls, there is no error but as soon as there is anything in the field it will error at runtime.

Comment: Have you looked at p before "Seq.map(fun p -> p.MapTo<Product>()" e.g. insert "|> Seq .map id" line before and so inspect p before the MapTo  function? Or try property by property assignment  it presumably is to SellDiscountCalcTypeId but what is the source type there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `MapTo` method doesn't seem to honor the `UseOptionTypes` flag. You can work around this, but it's not pretty. One way is to manually map the column:

```
let mapping (col : string, value : obj) =
    match col with
        | "SellDiscountCalcTypeId" ->
            if isNull value then None
            else Some (value :?> Guid)
            :> obj
        | _ -> value

let products = 
    query {
        for product in ctx.Dbo.Products do
            select product
    } 
    |> Seq.map (fun p -> p.MapTo<Product>(mapping))   // use manual mapping
    |> Seq.toList
```

Another is to explicitly select the individual fields. This will honor the `UseOptionTypes` flag, at least:

```
module Product =

    let create (id, sellDiscountCalcTypeId, code) =
        {
            Id = id
            SellDiscountCalcTypeId = sellDiscountCalcTypeId
            Code = code
        }

let products = 
    query {
        for product in ctx.Dbo.Products do
            select (product.Id, product.SellDiscountCalcTypeId, product.Code)   // explicitly select fields
    } 
    |> Seq.map Product.create
    |> Seq.toList
```